# How to get the count of repeater item in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How to get the count of repeater item in *JavaScript*?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"   
    OnPreRender="Repeater1_PreRender">
    <ItemTemplate>    
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can count in server side the number of item of datasource(datatable.Rows.Count for datatable or if list List.count...) and save it in a  javascript variable.

For example if your datasource is a list.

```
int count = yourList.Count;
repetear.DataSource = yourList;
...

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "countRepeaterItems",
                    string.Format("var countRepetear = {0};", count ));
```

now you have a variable countRepetear javascript with the number of items